# Change $.ajax to $post in rails

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below the code, I am using an ajax call for post request.Now I need to change from `$.ajax` to `$.post`.How to change below data with respect to `$.post`?

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "get_object",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        parameter: parameter_name,
        mac: macAdd,
        protocol: protocol,
        serialnumber: serialnumber,
        oid: oid
    },

    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        NProgress.done();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post(
     "get_object",
      {
        parameter: parameter_name,
        mac: macAdd,
        protocol: protocol,
        serialnumber: serialnumber,
        oid: oid
    },
    function (result, status) {
        console.log(result);

    },
    "json" 

 ).done(function() {
       NProgress.done();
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });
```

> [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thans.Now i am facing issue Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Comment: Sorry i dont know rails but i think you have to send the CSRF token in headers but in $.post  we cant send the headers, you can set up that by using  ```javascript                                                                                                                    $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {

            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        
    }
})```

Comment: yes.Thanks.I have changed as you mentioned.Now i am getting Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.